# Error in c sharp code

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issue using switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047403/issue-using-switch-case-statement)

I have code like this currently

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace Excel1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        //public void ExcelOps()
        {
            //string str;
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/WebServiceTemplate.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            int numSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            //
            // Iterate through the sheets. They are indexed starting at 1.
            //
            for (int sheetNum = 1; sheetNum <=1; sheetNum++)
            {
                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[sheetNum];
                //
                // Take the used range of the sheet. Finally, get an object array of all
                // of the cells in the sheet (their values). 
                //
                object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
                //
                // Do something with the data in the array with a custom method.
                //                
                ProcessInput(valueArray);
            }
        }
        public static void ProcessInput()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something with the data in the array with a custom method. When I run it, I get an error "Error   No overload for method 'ProcessInput' takes 1 arguments"

What is wrong? How do I go ahead and rectify this?

Comment: It means that the `ProcessInput` method is not visible from where you are calling it. Where is it defined?

Comment: Where is 'ProcessInput'  defined? You are calling it as if it is a member method of your Program.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Pls check the question now

Comment: @ebad86 Kindly check the question now...

Comment: Can you please create new questions for new problems, or edit your question in a way that your previous problems are not deleted? SO is meant as a permanent resource, and someone who visits this question tomorrow will not be able to figure out what most of our current answers refer to. Thank you.

Comment: Also, as for your latest edit, please explain what you have tried and why it did not work. The error message states the problem very clearly.

Comment: Possible homework since the code is exactly the same as in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047403/issue-using-switch-case-statement

Answer (score 8):

**if** this is a **complete** code, the compiler is absolutely right.

You don't have **any** `ProcessInput(..);` function definition in this code.

**EDIT**

Looking on *edited* post would say that what you missed is declaring your `ProcessInput` functions like a `static`

```
    public static void ProcessInput()
    {
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Now (after the edit to your question) the problem is that you are calling an instance method (`ProcessInput`) without having an instance of your class `Program` (`Main` is a static method).

Mark `ProcessInput` as *static*, too, to solve the problem:

```
public static void ProcessInput()
{
}
```

Alternatively, create an instance of your `Program` class and call the method on that:

```
Program prg = new Program();
prg.ProcessInput();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to

```
public static void ProcessInput()
{
}
```