# Issue using switch case statement

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

My code is as follows. Basically, I am reading an excel file and storing its contents into an object array. Then, I use a switch case statement to do different operations. Check my code below:-

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace Excel1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        //public void ExcelOps()
        {
            //string str;
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/WebServiceTemplate.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            int numSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            //
            // Iterate through the sheets. They are indexed starting at 1.
            //
            for (int sheetNum = 1; sheetNum <=1; sheetNum++)
            {
                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[sheetNum];
                //
                // Take the used range of the sheet. Finally, get an object array of all
                // of the cells in the sheet (their values). 
                //
                object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

                //
                // Do something with the data in the array with a custom method.
                //                
                ProcessInput(valueArray);
            }
        }
        public static void ProcessInput(object[,] valueArray)
        {
            foreach (var value in valueArray)
            {
                switch ((string)value.ToString())
                {
                    case "ITemplate.GetAllTemplate":
                        {
                            //ITemplate.GetAllTemplate
                            break;
                        }
                    case "ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate":
                        {
                            //ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate
                            break;
                        }
                    case "CreateTask":
                        {
                            //CreateTask
                            break;
                        }
                    case "UpdateDatabase":
                        {
                            //UpdateDatabase
                            break;
                        }
                    case "GetTaskStatus":
                        {
                            //GetTaskStatus
                            break;
                        }
                    case "VerifyValue":
                        {
                            //VerifyValue
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I build it, I get an error 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
the error appears in the switch statement

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi. You must pass array element but not whole array.

Comment: Have you even tried looking at least MSDN for switch case ?

Comment: And the comments in the cases are the same of the values in excel cells in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044835/parsing-an-excel-file-and-reading-a-cell/11045564#11045564) question by [Harish Kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1034945/harish-kumar)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`valueArray` is a multidimensional array of objects, according to your parameter definition. `switch` does not support that.

1. You can't and wouldn't perform a switch on an array of values; `switch` operates on a single value. You can use `foreach` to flatten the array, iterate over each value, and apply the switch, however...
2. As the error indicates, `object` cannot be used in `switch` statements, only types those indicated in the error message. If each value is an integer, cast the value to an int in the `switch`.

**Update** OK, now they are strings again.

Example:

```
foreach(var value in valueArray)
{
    switch(value as string)
    {
        case "ITemplate.GetAllTemplate":
                    break;
        case "ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate":
                    break;
        case "CreateTask":
                    break;
        case "UpdateDatabase":
                    break;
        case "GetTaskStatus":
                    break;
        case "VerifyValue":
                    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u help me as to how v can loop through each dimension and apply d switch?

Comment: mine contains only characters like words...so?

Comment: Just cast to whatever the actual type is. "characters like words"; so cast to `string` instead of `int` and change cases to `"1"` instead of `1` (or whatever the actual values are that you are interested in).

Comment: Hi..i did what u suggested...but i get this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'." The error is coming in the switch statement..any fix pls ?

Comment: OK, so the value of each item is `Double`. Cast to that instead.

Comment: how do v do so ? pls..am new to c sharp...

Comment: Ah, I forgot you can't use `double` in a switch, either. I suppose you could try `ToString()`-ing it and make the case values strings. I'm not sure how well that will work out, but you can try it. Your other option is to just use a series of `if` statements. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: yeah...pls...a little code could be very useful...kindly help

Comment: hi..i ToString() it as u said..Now, i m getting a new error...Pls check d code i have updated above..pls try running it...see if a solution is possible to just make d code build and run without giving any runtime error...

Comment: It seems the data you think you are getting from the spreadsheet is a not what you are actually getting. You're receiving a bunch of `double` floating-point numbers, and I don't know how those values correlate to stuff like `ITemplate.GetAllTemplate`.

Comment: no no..when i run d code and use breakpoints and check d valueArray, i see that it is loaded with the actual data from the excel file...there is nothing wrong in dat front..any idea?

Comment: What data is it loaded with? Now I'm confused. It was insinuated they were integers, then you say they are strings, but the error suggests they are double. So when you .ToString, you say you are seeing a new error. The error is a `NullReferenceException`? I'll update my answer again.

Answer (score 6):

The error message refers to the type of the variable in the brackets after your `switch`. In your case, this is an array, so obviously not (as the error message says) *a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type*.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite self explaining: you can't use the `switch` statement with `valueArray` object because of its type (`object[,]`).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not supported by Switch. It takes a single argument and Cases should be defined according to it.

Ex:

```
     int num=3;
     switch(num)  //in case of integer type
         Case 1:
         Case 2:
         ...
     }


     char ch='a';
     switch(ch)  //in case of character type
     {
         Case 'a':
         Case 'b':
         Case '/':
         ...
     }
```